# Robot Framework - How to use Global Variable for different keywords

Tags: variables, robotframework

I have this problem where I need to make a variable accessible from different keywords

I have Tried to use `set global variable` Keyword.

```
***Keywords***

Random Name
    ${Name}=  Full Name
    set global variable  ${Name}

Keyword Name
    Random Name
    Log  ${Name}

Keyword Name2
    Random Name
    Log  ${Name}


*** Test Cases ***
Run Keywords
    Keyword Name
    Keyword Name2
```

Full Name Keyword

```
Import names

def Full_Name(self):

    return (names.get_first_name())
```

Output

[image]

So in Keyword Name The value I am getting is `John`, but in Keyword Name2 The value is `Clair`. I need to keep the value as `John` for all of the keywords.

When i try to use the variable without passing the Keyword into the keyword I am not able to access it all.

I also Tried to use `set suite variable` but that has the Same Result.

Note: Full Name keyword is a custom library to get random names. also this is only a example code

Comment: This code won't run, it is full of errors. If it did run, it likely still wouldn't reproduce the problem since you call `Random Name` in every keyword so it stands to reason you would get a random name in every keyword (assuming `Random Name` actually sets `${name}` to a random name).

Comment: This is a sample code (My code is too large to post it here), I am calling the  `Random Name` keyword in every keyword because the global variable `${Name}` is not found otherwise, thats my problem, i need to use the `${Name}` without passing in the whole keyword. And `Random Name` does set `${Name}` to a random name

Comment: @BryanOakley i have edited my answer

Comment: The code you posted still doesn't work. I get `No keyword with name 'Full Name' found.`. When I fix the obvious error, both of the other keywords log "Full Name" just as I would expect.

Comment: @BryanOakley The Full Name Keyword is a custom keyword, I update my question

Comment: Even if i change ${Name} to a string I still cant access it

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. When I run your code, the log statements all log the correct value. You are using `Set Global Variable` correctly, though you only need to call it once. Once it's set, it's set for the life of the test run.

Comment: I've edited my answer once more I got a solution, I will Leave it here in case someone runs into the same problem

Comment: @WojtekT You should put into an answer and not as an edit to the question itself. :)

Comment: @WojtekT I removed your answer from the question because it should be posted as an answer. Self-answering questions is encouraged, and by posting the answer in the answer box you can even accept your own answer.

Comment: My bad, I have placed an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. I wasn't calling the Random Name Keyword in my Test case, and also i created a empty variable in the Variable section

```
 *** Variables ***
${Name}

***Keywords***

Random Name
    ${Name}=  Full Name
    set global variable  ${Name}

Keyword Name
    Log  ${Name}

Keyword Name2
    Log  ${Name}


*** Test Cases ***
Run Keywords
    Random Name
    Keyword Name
    Keyword Name2
```

Now I am getting the Desired output

Answer (score 0):

I know you already got it to work over two years ago but in case someone else stumbles here I'd like to propose an alternative:

```
*** Keywords ***

Setup: Run Keywords
    Set Test Variable    ${Name}    Full Name

Keyword Name
    Log    ${Name}

Keyword Name2
    Log    ${Name}


*** Test Cases ***

Run Keywords
    [Setup]    Setup: Run Keywords
    Keyword Name
    Keyword Name2
```

Using setups allow you to use variables appropriate to their usage better. I pretty much never need to use Global Variables unless I have multiple test suites related to each other and they'd have such similar suite setups that I make an init.robot to set them all up using Global Variables.